# selectedindexchanged event not firing on radiobuttonlist

Tags: .net, selectedindexchanged

I apply onselectedindexchangedevent on radiobuttonlist but when I click on
     radiobuttton  ,radiobutton is not selecting for a movement, it select,and then
     deselect .I also set postback=true.but it is not firing ..

```
**.aspx** 

      <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                    <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server"   
    AutoPostBack="true"RepeatDirection="Horizontal"OnSelectedIndexChanged="clicked"> 

                    <asp:ListItem Value="agree" Selected="True" ></asp:ListItem>
                       <asp:ListItem Value="agree"></asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:RadioButtonList>

                    </ItemTemplate>

                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>


    **.aspx.cs**



     public void clicked(object sender, EventArgs arg)
        {

            test t = new test();
            questiondal d = new questiondal();

            GridViewRow row= (( RadioButtonList  )sender).NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
      RadioButtonList list= (RadioButtonList )row.FindControl("Radio");
    list.SelectedIndexChanged();
     Label4.Text= list.SelectedValue;




        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that you gridview is not reloading when the postback occurs.
Ensure that your code is something like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    If(!IsPostBack)
    {
       GridView1.DataSource = dataTable;
       GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

When the radio button event is fired the Page_Load event is fired again but the grid won't refresh and the Clicked method will fire.

Answer (score 0):

Try change your code:

```
RadioButtonList list= (RadioButtonList )row.FindControl("Radio");
```

To:

```
RadioButtonList list= (RadioButtonList )row.FindControl("RadioButtonList1");
```

As there is no control in your gridview named 'Radio'.
Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: i do it, but still event is not firing

Comment: can you paset your code for selectedindexchanged that you call in line:
list.SelectedIndexChanged();